# Accessing a Class that is NOT declared in App_Code in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I sometimes define Business Logic classes to "help" my ASPX code-behind classes.  It makes the most sense to me to include them both in the code-behind file since they work together.  However, I'd occasionally like to access the Business Logic classes from higher level classes defined in App_Code but they aren't automatically accessible outside of the file.

Thus, the question: it is easy to access classes defined in App_Code but how do I access classes defined elsewhere?

UPDATE: One other thing, the ASPX page class and the App_Code class are in the same namespace - that isn't the issue.

NOTE: I have taken the advice of those who have responded (thanks guys) and am refactoring to make class access easier.  However, I don't think the question is actually answered yet (in the case of an ASP.NET Website project).  I don't *need* the answer any more but, if someone could clarify what makes classes visible when they are outside of App_Code, it may well help someone else (or even me, down the road).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean you are defining a separate class inside the codebehind .cs file? What access modifiers are you giving them?

As above though, I'd generally have a separate project in the solution for this kind of thing (usually in a different namespace like MyApp.Web and MyApp.), and just reference it from there.

Comment: Yes - it is a separate class inside the codebehind .cs file.  They are all public.  These "helper" classes provide page-specific business logic but I'm a bit loath to place them all in a separate project because they deal so intimately with the needs of the corresponding page.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you place your classes in a sensible namespace.

Place 'using' keyword in code behind files you would like to access them.

Or <%@ import if you are using them in inline code.

Put the dll that contains your classes in the /bin folder.

TBH I prefer to keep the separate library project in the same solution and have project reference in the Web probject.  VS handles building and placing the dll for you.

Comment: Thanks Anthony.  I don't need the using keyword (or import) because these classes are in the same namespace and project).  I think you may be right about a separate library project - especially for my DAL.  If my business logic was in a separate project it would make nUnit testing easier too...

Answer (score 3):

Some time while you create or add any file it has been create as the content file while it has to be compile file.

Please follow the process how to resolve this issue.

1) Right click on your class file in App_Code folder.
2) Click on properties.
3) Change Build Action from "" to Compile
4) Rebuild your Application.

### This will work definitely

Tushar Tyagi

Comment: Just as FYI for anyone finding this - you can get to the classes from your web page code-behind doing this, and setting the Build Action to Compile is the right way for doing that, but it's not a magic bullet. I ran into an issue when moving my project's target framework from .NET 4.5.2 to 4.0 where I had App_Code classes that called methods in other App_Code classes and it could no longer do that after my downgrade.  I had to replace App_Code with a standard folder I named "AppCode" and move my classes into that folder in order to get it to work again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just create a standard folder in your project to access classes, and move them there, but you have to do some additional things to make it accessible to your project:

- Ensure you don't name the folder any of the reserved terms (i.e. call it "AppCode", instead of "App_Code") if you are running into issues with the "App_Code" folder, after going through the rest of these bullets.
- The classes should all have the same namespace as your code-behind.
- Ensure the classes are made public, with public methods, if they are being called from other classes.
- Include "using MyClass;" statements at the top of the code-behind/class files.
- Make sure the class' Build Action property is set to Compile.

Answer (score -2):

You can not access a class from another class in same code behind file as .net dsnt support multiple inheritance. but you can create you business logic class as inner class in main class and make its all functions public so that they can be call in main class.

Comment: I don't think you quite got the gist of the question.  I wasn't trying to do multiple inheritance.  First, you can have more than one class in a code behind and one can call into the other. It appears that you just can't access a class in one codebehind from another codebehind.  Honestly, I don't even do this...I was just curious as to whether this is a hard-coded constraint of the language.  At this point, I have most classes defined in a Business Logic layer anyway and no such constraints exist there.  But thanks for trying!

Comment: As I understand what is being said, this answer is just plain wrong. Say you have a class file in your project that has a single namespace (matches code-behind) and then 2 classes within it. As long as the methods inside those classes are made public, one class CAN call those methods in the other, or be called from code-behind. It also seems the 1st sentence is saying you can't do this, with 2nd sentence saying you can, but you have to make it an "inner" class in your main one, which you 1) don't need to do, & 2) shouldn't do, anyway. Each class should really be separate-not inside the other.