# Cant access classes in App_Code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, oop

I have a VS web application that I'm working on. For some reason I can't access any of my classes (objects, methods, etc) in my App_Code directory. I even created a simple one....

```
Public Class Class1
    Public Sub xxxx()

    End Sub
End Class
```

I get a "Class1 is not defined" error. Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to call App\_Code class from a code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204990/unable-to-call-app-code-class-from-a-code-behind)

Comment: In short, App_Code is NOT for your code. Add you class to the root or another standard folder.

Comment: The problem is that for the vb class file I have to goto properties and change it to 'Compile'. Then it worked. Thanks everyone!