# App_code codefiles unaccessable when "web site" is published

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, app-code

When I test my web site (asp.net c# .net4) on the localhost, everything works fine. 
However, when I publish it to my webserver, I get the error:

```
 Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MyWhateverNamedHere' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

My code file (MyWhateverNamedHere.**cs**) lives in my App_Code folder, which *IS* moved to the webserver.

I have read where people move codefiles out of the App_Code folder. Didn't work for me. I tried giving them namespaces, and static references and just about everything I can think of. Then I found a solution that said *Build Phases > Compile*. But that's not an option for "web sites".

[image]

Any help?

Comment: Microsoft has deprecated Web Site Project almost a decade. Could you not able to convert it to Web Application Project?

Comment: Then why is it the second option in creating a new project in VS2013?

Comment: That is a good question. I guess it is a backward compatibility reason. Is there a reason not to use Web Application Project, because Web Application Project is [recommended for new projects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: I tried starting a new WAP and added the my codefiles to the project, gave them namespaces, the project could never see it.

Comment: This time you can change [build action to complie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204990/unable-to-call-app-code-class-from-a-code-behind/14206137#14206137).