# DLL References doesn't work in App_Code classes

Tags: asp.net, dll, app-code

I get some troubles with a DLL reference.

I have MySql.Data.dll in my bin folder. And I added the reference of this dll to my project.

I can well use classes from this dll (like MySqlConnection, MySqlClient, etc) in aspx.cs but i cannot use it in classes from files from App_Code folder !

For all files situated in App_Code folder (my model classes) , the `using MySql.Data;` doesn't work. While it works in aspx.cs files.

Comment: Is this a web application project, or a web site project (File->New Web Site)?

Comment: It's a web application project. I started by an empty asp project.

Comment: Ok, suggestion: don't use App_Code. Real programmers use real folders and real namespaces.

Comment: @dramixx Did you look at this problem - [Can't debug class within App_Data folder](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14206137/296861)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you know, there are two types of projects that you can use to create a website in Visual Studio. The App_Code folder works for Web Site projects, but since you stated that you're using a Web Application project, this is causing you problems.

[Here's some additional reading on this topic.](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html)

In short, I recommend just creating a different (non-built-in) folder to put your random code files in. Name it something like "code", "classes", etc.