# How to inherits a class located in the App_Code folder from a web.config section? What would be the namespace?

Tags: asp.net

I've created a class and placed in the App_Code folder. When I try to access from the Web.config file, I'me getting an exception: **The profile default provider was not found**.

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="CustomUserProfile">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="ProfileProvider"
       connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer"
       type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, 
       System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, 
       Culture=neutral, 
       PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
       description="SqlProfileProvider extra fields"
       applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
  </profile>
```

When I add this code:

```
<profile defaultProvider="SqlProvider" inherits="MyApp.App_Code.CustomUserProfile">
```

I'm getting a different error.

```
Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'MyApp.App_Code.CustomUserProfile' is not defined.
```

I'd like to know what's the namespace for a file located in the App_Code folder?

Thank for helping.

Comment: try MyApp.CustomUserProfile

Comment: Removing `App_Code` puts me back the previous error, which is: `The profile default provider was not found.`

Comment: Why not add a namespace around your class so that you know explicitly what it will be?

Comment: Wrapping up the class inside an explicit namespace didn't solve the problem. I'm still getting the same error: `The profile default provider was not found.`

Comment: Does [unable to call App_Code class from a code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14206137/296861) relate to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DefaultProvider should match the name added in providers, like this:

```
<profile defaultProvider="ProfileProvider" inherits="CustomUserProfile">
```

Comment: I've two makes two changes. 1) as suggested some other places, change the build action to compile 2) prepend the name of the project to the name of the class like this `inherits="MyApp.CustomUserProfile"`. Besides that, the big problem is what you pointed out, i.e. I did just copy/paste without paying attention to the content. The default provider name should be the same as the provider I've added. Thank you so much.