# in app_code namespace I don't have .ToList() and FirstOrDefault() method like in Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to have a global method that all of my controllers can access to it.
in this method I want to connect to Database as I connect in my controllers.
following code works fine in my controllers but when i move this code to App_Code it has some Error ! I need this method in all of my controllers so what do I do ? instead of .FirstOrDefault() I have .FirstOrDefaultAsync() ! why ?

```
using Sitaad.Models;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Sitaad.App_Code
{
    public class Reg
    {
        private string _lang = "Fa";
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public string T(string txt)
        {
            string query = "select Text from Translations where Code = '@p1' and TranslateId = (select TranslateId from Translations where Text = '@p2')";
            Translations t = db.Translation.SqlQuery(query,
                                           TurboSofts.Lang.T.GetLang(),
                                           txt).FirstOrDefault(); /* this line can't run */
            return t.Text;
                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: What is the error ? Where are you creating the object `db` ?

Comment: [Unable to call App_Code class from a code-behind](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14206137/296861)

Comment: the db is : `private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicatoinDbContex();` and whole of this method is in a class in App_Code folder

Comment: I Found half of the solution I had to 
inherit from Controller class
`public class Reg {...}` => `public class Reg : Controller {...}`
but still I don't have .ToList() in `T` method instead of .ToList() i have a .ToListAsync() why ?

Comment: @Shyju I edited my question