# Class in App_Code not accessible

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a `Config.cs` file inside the `App_Code` folder:

```
namespace C
{
public class Config
{
  ......
 }
 }
```

In my default.aspx.cs page, I added `using C;` but I can't load the page. It says:

`CS0246: The type or namespace name 'C' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

I'm using CodeFile instead of CodeBehind and I already tried to set the Build Action property to `Compile` but I cant find that option in the class properties page. I am using VS 2012.

It works fine though when I press F5 in VS 2012 and access my site under that port. It only show error when I try to access my page directly, as any other user would try to.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222281/classes-residing-in-app-code-is-not-accessible/37818086#37818086

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `App_Code` folder is not in root folder of project. Please make sure that you have put `App_code` folder in project path which contains `default.aspx` file. Don't keep `App_code` within a nested folder.

Comment: App_Code folder is already in my root folder. In my `inetpub` folder there's a folder named `painel` and inside that folder there's all my aspx pages, including `App_Code` folder.

Comment: just open your website in VS from path .../inetpub/painel1/ and then try to compile..

Comment: I solved it by moving the `App_Code` from `painel` directory and placing it under `wwwroot` folder along with my `web.config` file. Odd, but it works fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to pre-compile the application and publish on server. If it is not precompiled, make sure the class file exists in server 'App_Code' folder. When the application receives first request, this class gets compiled.

Answer (score 0):

You should just edit the Properties of the class files in Visual Studio and mark the Build Action as "Compile", instead of "Content", then rebuild and re-publish your project.