# ASP.NET App_Code in folder

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, app-code

I am working on a ASP.NET VB project. The host is pretty restrictive, so the App_Code folder has to be placed under the wwwroot folder.

My current folder structure (on the server) looks like this:

```
root
  <-- Cant create folders or files here, host is restrictive.
  wwwroot
       App_Code 
           Class.VB
       Styles
            style.css
       default.aspx
       web.config
```

It seems to be working, if Class.vb contains errors, i get a compilation error on the website, so i know its compiling the class.

But i am unable to use the class in my other code files.

Example:

```
Dim emailFilter As Validation = New Validation()
```

I get this error in VS2010:

```
Type 'Validation' is not defined
```

How do i use the App_Code folder when its inside another folder?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be an issue with namespaces?  I might be more inclined to create a library for your validation class and add a reference to it instead.

I did find some similar issues to yours and they all referenced setting the Build Action for the class to 'compile'.

[Classes residing in App_Code is not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222281/app-code-classes-not-accessable-asp-net)