# Issue in accessing class from App_Code

Tags: asp.net

I have created a class CustomEditor(inside App_Code folder) which is inherited from Editor class of AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor namespace.

Inside the class I have overridden 2 methods

```
protected override void FillTopToolbar()
{
TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new Bold());            
TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new Italic());
TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new Underline());
}

protected override void FillBottomToolbar()
{
BottomToolbar.Buttons.Add(new DesignMode());
BottomToolbar.Buttons.Add(new HtmlMode());
}
```

Now I am using this in an aspx page

```
<%@ Register Namespace="MyControls" TagPrefix="HTMLEditor"  %>
<HTMLEditor:CustomEditor runat="server" Height="500px" Width="100%" ID="editor" AutoFocus="true" />
```

When I run the page I can see the editor successfully, but I want to access it in the designer. I am getting this compile time error - "The type or namespace name 'CustomEditor' does not exists in the namespace .."

I am using visual studio 2012. How can I fix it?

I have checked this thread of yours as well - "[Classes residing in App_Code is not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222281/app-code-classes-not-accessable-asp-net)" but I didn't find the Build Action property

Comment: Have you declared namespace `MyControls` in that class file?

Comment: No. But I am accessing the control like MyControls.CustomEditor

Comment: Hi Please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

In your `.cs` file declare:

```
namespace MyControls
{
    public class CustomEditor
    {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue got resolved after the class is recreated. Thank you

Comment: Yep, stating the obvious, here, now, but you can't reference a namespace/class that doesn't exist... that's why you got the error. @Taosique, great job figuring this out - wasn't obvious until the answer got posted. :)