# Type conflict when trying to derive from another class in the App_Code folder in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a base class which implements the `IRouteConstraint` interface. I'm trying to extend that class and override the `Match()` method defined in the base class. This is for an ASP.NET MVC5 application using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2.

My classes are structured like this:

*\Project\App_Code\BaseRouteConstraint.cs:*

```
namespace Website {
    public class BaseRouteConstraint: IRouteConstraint {
        public virtual bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {
            ...code
        }
    }
}
```

*\Project\App_Code\DerivedRouteConstraint.cs:*

```
namespace Website {
    public class DerivedRouteConstraint: BaseRouteConstraint {
        public override bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection) {
            if(!base.Match(httpContext, route, values, routeDirection) {
                ...code
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't actually use the DerivedRouteConstraint class because Visual Studio says it doesn't exist. I also get this warning:

> 'Website.BaseRouteConstraint' in
>   'C:\Project\App_Code\BaseRouteConstraint.cs' conflicts with the
>   imported type 'Website.BaseRouteConstraint' in 'C:\Project\'. Using
>   the type defined in 'C:\Project\App_Code\BaseRouteConstraint.cs'

I've checked and I haven't accidentally copied the source code file for my base class anywhere else in the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unbeknownst to me the App_Code folder doesn't work like a normal folder. I thought it was just a place to put any semi-random classes that didn't necessarily need their own folder in the project structure. While I was writing up this question I decided to try moving the files to a different (normal) folder and everything started working correctly.

The App_Code folder has special functionality and everything in it is compiled into a DLL and automatically referenced to the project. The "App Code" section on the MSDN page [Shared Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/t990ks23(v=vs.100).aspx) for more information about this folder. This forum post (http://forums.asp.net/t/1026147.aspx?+What+is+App_Code+Folder+for+) clued me in that the code is actually **referenced** back to the project, which is important to understanding the error.

The root of the problem was that I had changed the namespace that the classes resided in because I didn't want them to be in the `Website.App_Code` namespace. So when the files in the App_Code folder  were compiled and automatically referenced to the project I then had two definitions in the `Website` namespace for the `BaseRouteConstraint` class. (One from the reference App_Code DLL and one in the code itself.)

Changing the namespace back to `Website.App_Code` worked once I had also set the build option on the files to `Compile` instead of `Content` (based on this question: [Classes residing in App_Code is not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222281/classes-residing-in-app-code-is-not-accessible)). However, in this case I think it is more appropriate to move the files to their own normal folder in the project structure.