# UserControl not recognizing class in app_Code

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a class called `CatalogAccess` in the `app_Code` folder and a `DataList` user control in a folder called `UserControls` which is in the root folder. The `UserControl` is used to display a list of departments that are being pulled in the `CatalogAccess`. I call the `GetDepartments` function in the `CatalogAccess` class like this:

```
list.DataSource = CatalogAccess.GetDepartments();
list.DataBind();
```

However, intelisense keeps telling me that

> The name CatalogAccess does not exist in the current context

CatalogAccess class

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace techniccashregister.App_Code
{
    // Product catalog business tier component
    public static class CatalogAccess
    {
        static CatalogAccess()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

        public static DataTable GetDepartments()
        {
            // Get a configured DbCommand object
            DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
            // Set the stored procedure name
            comm.CommandText = "GetDepartments";
            // Exectute the store procedure and return the results
            return GenericDataAccess.ExecuteSelectCommand(comm);
        }
    }
}
```

User Control

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using techniccashregister.App_Code;

namespace techniccashregister.UserControls
{
    public partial class DepartmentsList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            list.DataSource = CatalogAccess.GetDepartments();
            list.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Class Accessing data

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace techniccashregister.App_Code
{
    // This class contains generic data access functionality to be accessed from the business tier
    public static class GenericDataAccess
    {
        // Static constructor
        static GenericDataAccess()
        {
            //
            // TODO: Add constructor logic here
            //
        }

        // Executes a commmand and returns the results as a DataTable object
        public static DataTable ExecuteSelectCommand(DbCommand command)
        {
            // The DataTable to be returned
            DataTable table;
            // Execute the command, making sure the connection gets closed in the end
            try
            {
                // Open the data connection
                command.Connection.Open();
                // Execute the command and save the results in a DataTable
                DbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                table = new DataTable();
                table.Load(reader);

                // Close the reader
                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Utilities.LogError(ex);
                throw;
            }

            finally
            {
                // Close the connection
                command.Connection.Close();
            }

            return table;
        }

        // Creates and prepares the new DbCommand object on a new connection
        public static DbCommand CreateCommand()
        {
            // Obtain the database provider name
            string dataProviderName = technicConfiguration.DbProviderName;
            // Obtain the database connection string
            string connectionString = technicConfiguration.DbConnectionString;
            // Create the new data provider factory
            DbProviderFactory factory = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(dataProviderName);
            // Obtain a database-specific connection object
            DbConnection conn = factory.CreateConnection();
            // Set the connection string
            conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
            // Create a database-specific command object
            DbCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            // Set the command type to stored procedure
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            // Return the initialized command object
            return comm;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what can I do to fix this?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi T.S.  For what I can see, both of them have the namespace.

Comment: Everything has namespace. There are two reasons, your class is not visibile - 1. It is in different namespace and your namespace is not imported. 2. your class is not public enough to be visible. Remember - you're in a web site project. If you use App_Code, you building many DLLs and your user control may not see whats in some class. Can you post declaration of your class ?

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace techniccashregister.App_Code
{
    // Product catalog business tier component
    public static class CatalogAccess
    {

Comment: Sorry, that did not come out so good.  That was the catalogAccess class.

Comment: using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace techniccashregister.UserControls
{
    public partial class DepartmentsList : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: This is the code behind the UserControl

Comment: @user3294748 You should poste code in the question itself, rather than trying to shoehorn it into comments.

Comment: @user3294748 - Add to user control `using techniccashregister.App_Code;`

Comment: It did not work.  I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: Those are my complete classes.

Comment: Does this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1222293/1191903 help?

Comment: Hi Kevin.  I changed it from content to compile and it just threw more errors.

Comment: @user3294748 what sort of errors?

Comment: Oh nvm.  I just changed all the classes to compile and it works now.  Thank you so much guys.  You are great.

Comment: @KevinMain  I don't even have this option in properties

Comment: I am using VS 2012.  If you click on your classes it should show Build Action as the third selection in properties.

Comment: @user3294748 I am also using vs2012. Is your project WSP or WAP?

Comment: No, is just a regular project for school so I am just writing code in the file system without even using IIS or anything else.

Comment: Lets ask this... When you right-click on your project in solution explorer, does it say **Build** or **Build Web Site** in one of the menus on top?

Comment: Yes, it is the first selection.  Build then Rebuild, Publish...

Comment: Ah... That explains it. I thought you have WSP. You shouldn't even have App_Code folder to begin with. That confused me. In WAP you can better define your namespaces. Read this , all way to the end. http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2009/07/appcode-folder-doesnt-work-with-web.html