# Class not available

Tags: asp.net

İ create a project "Deneme". create a folder as "App_Code" and create a class Islem in this folder. Then i create new aspx page but i couldn't see this class.error message is "Deneme is available Deneme is not availabe" I couldn't understand. My friend cab see this class on his computer but I can't. I created a new webform `default.aspx`. I couldn't reach this class, but I can reach `webform1.aspx` in this folder.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us the code for the class.

Comment: there is nothing, i wrote only one void metod.Usings are cant solve. Can i  show you by teamviever if you let me

Comment: Was the class marked as private?

Comment: No,i try for this more than 2 days. if you let me can i show you please.can we talk ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provide namespace in your Islem.cs like this

```
namespace Deneme
{
 public class Islem
 {
    // .... logic
 }
}
```

create new class in App_Code folder, there is no namespace by default. so you can no access it.

Comment: if you let me i want to show you by teamviewer,as i told dear Irish.

Comment: İ couldnt solve this little problem more than 2 days.i am about to kill myshelf for this problem:))

Comment: upload snapshot of your Islem.cs class

Comment: i uploaded.İf you let me you can connect by teamviever dear friend

Comment: i think problem in WebForm1.aspx. because it is in same folder and how you can add this aspx page. let me know. check WebForm1.aspx page namesapce. both are same or different

Comment: i found the solution...in your solution your project name is **Deneme** and other class name is **Deneme.cs**... so it conflict...change your class name like Deneme12.cs

Comment: same. İ delete webform1.aspx but i cant reach Islem.cs from Default.aspx

Comment: Delete your deneme.cs class. then type in Default.cs like this Deneme.App_Code.Islem. i dont have teamviewer

Comment: upload your project to github or mail me

Comment: please dowload teamviever. I can show you everything.Because project is running other compuers but proble in here can i tell you

Comment: 471 642 266  pasword is 1876

Comment: can not connect with your Id

Comment: 471642266   and password 1507

Comment: my mobile number is +905465200320    i can send you screen of teamviever.it is my team viever ID and i wait you. you send me message by whatsapp if you want. how can i help you

Comment: i could not connect. share your skype account so i will connect

Comment: halid peynirci      can you tell me your skype name i will connect you  if you cant

Answer (score 0):

### Troubleshooting when you can't find a class

While working on the project, open the "Object Browser" from the "View" menu.  Then in the textbox labeled "Search" type in "Islem" and see what comes up.

If the class doesn't come up at all, you're in the wrong project, or you didn't add the class like you think you did, or it's a different project and you need to [add a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7314433t(v=vs.90).aspx).

If it does come up, take careful note of the class' complete namespace.

### My guess

My guess is that you have a mismatch on the namespace.  By creating the folder you created a sub-namespace by default, so you probably need to add something like this to the top of your code:

```
using Deneme.App_Code
```

or, if you don't want to add that for some reason, you can instantiate an instance of the class using its full name:

```
var o = new Deneme.App_Code.Islem();
```

### Another guess

Make sure Islem.cs is set to compile.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1222281/classes-residing-in-app-code-is-not-accessible) for instructions.

Comment: it couldnt solve my problem mr john.I cant reach classes if you have teamviever i can show you igf you let me

Comment: Were you able to find the class in the object browser?

Comment: i can find it by object browser

Comment: Edited my answer with another thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird situation but try this. Go to 14 line in your Default.aspx.cs file and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> then you will have a new Islem file i the root of your project. Rebuild and then your error will disappear. Then copy the code inside your original Islem to the new generated file. Remove the old Islem and move the new one to App_Code. Hope this help you.