# C# Custom EventHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have a custom event handler in the page, and it is called by the user controls of it.

everything is fine, except there is error display in the code ( red highlighted), but the program can be compiled, and able to run with no apparent error.

but i want to fix (or understand) the reason why the visual studio showed error for that

the error is [image]

the code is

-PAGE

```
Operator_agentcontrol2 agentcontrol = (Operator_agentcontrol2)Page.LoadControl("~/operator/agentcontrol2.ascx");
agentcontrol.displayLevel = (int)Common.WinLose_Level.lvChild4 + 10 + (Panel_agents.Controls.Count * 10);
agentcontrol.AppendProcess += Append_UC_Progress;//Error line
```

the event in the page-

```
public void Append_UC_Progress(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Common.WinLose_ProgressStage wps = (Common.WinLose_ProgressStage)e;
        progress.AppendProgress(wps);
        SaveProgressVS();
}
```

-USER CONTROL

```
public partial class Operator_agentcontrol2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<Common.WinLose_ProgressStage> AppendProcess;
}
```

Thanks

---Update---
I have tried to follow https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x(v=vs.85).aspx for the custom event handler.

but then i got this error 
[image]

---Update---
Eventually I found that actually my scenario doesn't require to use something like EventHandler

i have changed the code in user control

```
public partial class Operator_agentcontrol2 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler AppendProcess;
}
```

By doing this the error is gone, and the user control still able to call the Page's function successfully with an object Common.WinLose_ProgressStage.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, two errors are being reported...

1 - It cannot find a suitable overload for `Append_UC_Progess` (which takes a `Common.WinLose_ProgressStage` as an argument)

2 - The assembly containing `Common.WinLose_ProgressStage` is not referenced.

What I would suggest is happening, is that once it is all compiled the assembly containing `Common.WinLose_ProgressStage` gets pulled in (perhaps by another referenced assembly), and thus it is noticed that it inherits from `EventArgs`. It can therefore find a suitable overload of `Append_UC_Progess` and it all resolves ok.

In order to get rid of the error, I would suggest explicitly referencing the assembly containing `Common.WinLose_ProgressStage`, so that Visual Studio can see the inheritance tree at design time.

Comment: not really, Common.WinLose_ProgressStage is just a normal class file, there is many other class and variable in that file, the main different of WinLose_ProgressStage from other classes is just it inherited the EventArgs so that it can be put in EventHandler ( Please check the user_control code), thanks

Comment: Is it in the same assembly as the page?  The error suggests that it is not, and it is in an assembly called `App_Code.xyvqhtbf` that needs to be referenced from the page.

Comment: Or perhaps you have fallen into this trap: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1222293/3111401

Comment: i am using VS2015 and i didn't see properties in the drop down list, for the properties window below of the solution explorer, it doesn't contain the related field